# schoolproject extra function with new library

Tags: c, libraries

Tomorrow I have an exam for a C programming and we have to present a program we have made. I was assigned a postfix calculator and I finished this. But to get extra points, we have to add an extra function to the program that was not in the assignment text. We have to find something ourselves. They said it would be a nice if we used a library that is new to us. But I don't have any inspiration. I have less than 24 hours to finish and I have no clue what kind of libraries are out there or what I can do.

So, I need something to add to a postfix calculator working with a new library in C that is programmable in about 10 hours.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could add the trig functions from `math.h`: sin, cos, tan, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) library to add big number support to your calculator. Then you can calculate 10^500 / 2^230 if you have enough time ;-)

Comment: '10 500 ^ 2 230 ^ /` you meant